# Информация о причине блокировки участника не отображается в профиле на Мете

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация, мета, блокировка

В Мета профиле заблокированного участника не отображается информация о причине блокировки:

> [image: забанен без причины]

В профиле на основном сайте причина видна:

> [image: чтоб успокоился]

При этом, если открыть вкладку "Активность" профиля, текст имеет другую форму (не обращайте внимание на кол-во дней, просто прошли сутки уже с момента предыдущих скриншотов):

- на Мете:

  > [image: мета-активность]
- на основном:

  > [image: основная-активность]

Имеет смысл привести к единому виду, как мне кажется. Строки на transifex:

- [на вкладке "Активность"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267091?key=8644c735675dd166ac380a5aa25d4081)

  > This account is temporarily suspended$reason$. The suspension period ends $penaltyEndDate$.
- [на вкладке "Профиль"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40540310?key=229e40df2284bc1723ab27d08cd748eb)

  > This account is $linkStart$temporarily suspended$linkEnd$$reason$. The suspension period ends $penaltyEndDate$.

Comment: Возможно, база данных Меты не имеет доступа к данным (причине блокировки) с основного сайта. Уточню.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [meta-tag:требует-перевода] значит пока не ставим? :)

Comment: Ага. Я напрямую отпишусь ребятам. Если доступа нет, перенесем запятую в другу часть перевода!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky причина блокировки - возможность найти баг на SE. Кругом одна польза :)

Comment: Уточнил. Это не ошибка. Так задумано. Идея в том, чтобы отображать причину блокировки исключительно в том месте, где была блокировка. То есть если бы мы показывали причину блокировки и на Мете, можно было бы подумать, что участник сделал что–то не так на самой Мете.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky значит надо перевод адаптировать. Но вообще это всё странно. Зачем вообще писать о блокировке тогда. А почему строки разные для вкладок Профиль и Активность не выяснили?